# Get woocommerce product attributes to sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I want to display all the available product attributes in woocommerce sidebar. According to the design and plugins that I am using, it's hard to use widget boxes here.So I chose to loop all the product attributes available and show them in the sidebar.

I tried the following methods that available on woocommerce [docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable.html),

1. get_attribute()
2. get_attributes()
3. get_variation_attributes()

As well as tried some stack answers as well.

```
global $product;
$product->get_attributes();
```

But I am still getting an empty array.

**My sidebar is included in woocommerce archive page**. How can get the attribute name and it's values?

Comment: Have you load your content on any specific hook. Please check by using var_dump($product);

Comment: Please try by using $product_id = 10;$WC_Product = new WC_Product($product_id);
$var = $WC_Product->get_attributes( );

Comment: @dineshkashera It returns some product objects sir. If you want to visualize I can add the value to the question

Comment: @dineshkashera I want to show all the product attributes in the sidebar. When user clicks one of them I have to filter the products and give the result. `$WC_Product = new WC_Product($product_id);` this sounds like accessing a single product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Woocommerce dedicated `wc_get_attribute_taxonomies()` function in a custom shortcode function that will output the list of all product attributes.

Then you will be able to add it in a text widget on the sidebar *(see at the end)*.

The shortcode `[product_attributes]` code:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_attributes', 'get_product_attributes' );
function get_product_attributes() {
    $output = '<ul style="list-style:none;">';
    foreach( wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() as $attribute ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_' . $attribute->attribute_name;
        $term_names = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'fields' => 'names' ) );

        $output .= '<li><strong>' . $attribute->attribute_label . ':</strong> ' . implode( ', ', $term_names ) . '</li>';
    }
    return $output . '</ul>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

---

Then you will add a new text widget in your sidebar and you will paste the shortcode in the text editor to get the list of product attributes…

[image]